# With WebApplicationFactory, add configuration source before Program.cs executes

Tags: .net, integration-testing

I am using the new minimal .NET 6 hosting model, and I have an integration test.

Obviously `Program.cs` needs configuration values, so I want to use a custom `appsettings.Test.json` file. Docs say I can use `ConfigureAppConfiguration` but its delegate runs after `Program`, hence `Program` has no configuration. Here's the code added to the [Minimal API Playground sample code](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/tests/MinimalApiPlayground.Tests/PlaygroundApplication.cs):

```cs
internal class PlaygroundApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private readonly string _environment;

    public PlaygroundApplication(string environment = "Development")
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment(_environment);

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile(appSettings); // runs AFTER Program.cs
        });

        // Add mock/test services to the builder here
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
        });

        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

How can I provide configuration to `Program.cs`?

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var keyVaultName = builder.Configuration["KeyVaultName"]; // null

builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new SecretClient(
    new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/"),
    new DefaultAzureCredential()), new KeyVaultSecretManager());
```

I can set environment to `Test`and then in Program do:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json");

var keyVaultName = builder.Configuration["KeyVaultName"]; // has value from json

builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new SecretClient(
    new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/"),
    new DefaultAzureCredential()), new KeyVaultSecretManager());
```

But is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not possible with the way the code is written unfortunately, according to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37680.

Comment: This [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37680#issuecomment-1132045299) is working for me

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround that I detail here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37680#issuecomment-1032922656

If you override `WebApplicationFactory<T>.CreateHost()` and call `IHostBuilder.ConfigureHostConfiguration()` before calling `base.CreateHost()` the configuration you add will be visible inbetween `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()` and `builder.Build()`. From my testing it's visible in all the various places you'd look at the config (callbacks, etc.).

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on the previous answer, I can confirm that this works but as far as I can tell it works by passing the values from your `appsettings.Test.json` in through the `string[] args` of your entry point (your `program.cs`).

You can easily tell if it works by placing a breakpoint before `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` and inspecting the arguments.

The issue with this seems to me that any setting also defined in your `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.{environment}.json` will override your `appsettings.test.json` since they are applied afterwards.

One easy solution is to add your `appsettings.test.json` from within your project, if the file exists.

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "appsettings.test.json");
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(path, optional: true);
```

The `path` needs to be resolved like this since `WebApplicationFactory<EntryPoint>` will set the `content-root` setting to the project directory (of your entry point) by passing it into the `args`.

This is of course not ideal since the project should in theory not be aware of your tests at all but that is the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am depending on Manually resolving the value by reading the `appsettings.Test.json` as a Json file, as none of the above solution worked in dotnet 6.

```
public class FakeApplication<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IUserService, FakeUserService>();
services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(OverrideFromTestConfig()));
        });
    }

    private static DbClientConfig OverrideFromTestConfig()
    {
        var content = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "appsettings.test.json"));
        var config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(content);
        return config.GetProperty("Database").Deserialize<DbClientConfig>()!;
    }
}
```